# Table height exceeded page border

Tags: tables, floats, adjustbox

I know that some tricks, like using `adjustbox`, would restrict a table to the page length vertically. However, is there a similar approach to apply such a vertical length restriction?

Comment: it the table is to high, than see if the `longtable` is acceptable to you. it can split table over two (or more) pages. and not use `adjustbox`, rather see if you can make columns narrower (maybe with use smaller font size, but not to small). without seeing your table is difficult to say anything more.

Comment: @Zarko I am already using `\footnotesize` and `\small` but no use. How to narrow down rows?

Comment: using scaling like adjustbox on a table should only be the absolute last resort, but you don't give any information why your table is too wide, you can specify the column widths with `p{3cm}` or whatever width so you should never have a table wider than the page. Or perhaps you are looking for `longtable` to allow page breaking. As you show no code it is impossible to guess what you should change.

Comment: @Zarko Latex says `\arraystreatch` is undefined.

Comment: @Zarko Your comment had a typo. It is arraystretch. anyway, it fixed my issue.